# Read from a visual basic api an SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have not been able to find documentation to help me build a vb api that can read from a SQL Server stored procedure. I currently have an api that works, I was able to test my controller and the methods (GET, POST, ) work. Please let me know how can I read from a `.sql` file.

The code below is in Calendar Model - Calendar.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sqlFile As String = "C:\temp\test.sql"
        Dim sqlText = File.ReadAllText(sqlFile)
        Dim connStr = "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=testing; Integrated Security=SSPI"
        Dim conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)

        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlText, conn)

        Try
            conn.Open()
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Something went wrong: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't understand what the code you posted has to do with an API, or what you mean by a "vb api that can read sql stored procedures".  And why are you reading from a .sql file?

Comment: Do you want to read from a sql-file or from a sql-database-table?

Comment: Do you mean that `test.sql` contains a stored procedure that you want to run against the SQL Express database you're connecting to?  If so, that's not how it's done - you need to add the stored procedure to the database, then you can execute it with the various `Execute` methods.

Comment: Could you add the content of test.sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the test.sql execute a run of stored procedure and if it's return a table you can read as this :

```
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader(0))
    End While
```

If it's return one value use this

```
 intValue =Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Comment: This would be far more useful if he was using c#.